# Eclipse giving error when none are present (Snow Leopard and Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, osx-snow-leopard, java

I'm trying to build an Android project in Eclipse, there are no syntax errors in the code (there's not much code at this point so I'm sure of this), I clean the project and build it and there are no errors, but as soon as I try to launch the app I get an error message and an error symbol on the project folder.  This isn't the first time this has happened, I can't seem to launch any other projects either.  I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo), JDK 6 with the compiler in Eclipse set to use v1.6, and Snow Leopard 10.6.8.  I've tried fixing the project properties and still nothing works.  Any help please?

Are there any known compatibility issues with Eclipse Indigo, JDK 6 and Snow Leopard 10.6.8?

Comment: Did you look in the error/problems view?

Comment: I was concentrating on the LogCat and completely overlooked the Error/Problems view. It turns out that my Debug Certificate had expired so I just needed to delete ~/.android/debug.keystore and restart Eclipse and everything worked. Thanks much @Dave.

Comment: No problem; it can escape attention sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was concentrating on the LogCat and completely overlooked the Error/Problems view.  It turns out that my Debug Certificate had expired so I just needed to delete `~/.android/debug.keystore` and restart Eclipse and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Often, misspelled assets or graphics can cause this and not show any error.

I'd make sure there are no misspelled or invalid characters in your filenames.

Hope that helps

Comment: No, like I said, there's not much of anything as of yet so there's no errors.  I'm attempting to launch Google's Notepad tutorial and still on Exercise 1, so I've double checked everything against their samples and it's as it should be.